# wait function in multithreading in java

Tags: java, multithreading

how would this block of code work:

```
boolean flag=true;
while(flag){
    wait();
    flag=!flag;
}
```

will the flag = !flag ever be executed? Further, if set flag as a static variable(it is shared between the instances) and start two threads containing the following code:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
 flag=!flag;   
 while(flag){
        System.out.println("*");
        wait();
    } 
    notify();
}
```

Why does the program stop after printing a random number of '*'s? (even after using synchronization). Please explain the behavior of wait() inside while loop.

Comment: I think you need to read [some basic information on `wait()` and `notify()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html).

Comment: Could you attach full examples containing `main()` of your code, please? It's unclear whether these objects can be notified from other threads.

Comment: [this](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#synctr1) may help.

Answer (score 1):

> .wait() says “I’m done with my timeslice. Don’t give me another timeslice until someone calls notify().” The OS won’t even try to schedule your task unless someone calls notify() (or one of a few other wakeup scenarios occurs).
>
> will the flag = !flag ever be executed?

Yes, after the thread has been woken up.

> Further, if set flag as a static variable and start two threads containing the following code:

flag being static means it's shared between instances, right?

Assume flag starts out as true.

- You spawn one thread A.
- You spawn the other thread B. The threads start running after a random delay.
- A sets flag from false to true. A starts running the loop. A waits until it's woken up again.
- At some point B starts running. When it does so, it sets flag to false. B goes straight to notify(); The only one it notifies is itself.
- A continues to wait for notify(), B has terminated.
- If A is notified at some point, it will proceed in the loop, see that flag is no longer true and proceed and terminate.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I meant that flag is shared between instances, I have made a small edit to the question (added the for loop). What happens if there is no notify signal, will the thread keep waiting? What is difference between using if and while in the above code segment?

Comment: B isn't invoking notify on A. A will wait forever.

Comment: While is a loop, if is not.

Answer (score 1):

> will the flag = !flag ever be executed?

Yes. If another thread calls `notify()` or `notifyAll()` on this object, the `wait()` call returns and `flag` will be cleared, which results in the loop exiting.

> Why does the program stop after printing a random number of '*'s?

If the code is really as described, only two `*` should be printed, because a thread can't invoke `notify()` while it's in a `wait()` call, and no other thread is shown invoking `notify()`.

Please replace the fake code with a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example.](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full implementation:

```
class Test implements Runnable{
    static boolean flag=false;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Thread(this,"thread1").start();
        new Thread(this,"thread2").start();
    }
    public void run(){
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            flag=!flag;
             try{
                while(flag){
                System.out.println("*");
                wait();
                }
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                System.out.println("thread interrupted");
            }
            notify();
        }
    }
}
```

It works perfectly fine on replacing the while(flag) statement with if(flag) statement. When using while, it stops after giving some fraction of the complete output.

Comment: That can't be the full implementation. Calling `wait()` without synchronization on the instance will raise an `IllegalThreadStateException`. And your problem might have to do with where your `synchronized` block begins and ends, so that is very important. Also, you can't refer to `this` in a static method like `main()`. Is there some reason why you can't just post a working example of the problem you are asking us to solve?